# Magento 2 Widget filter option to add price

Tags: magento2, widget

When I select simple product from drop down under layout updates. I can select based on SKU, ID or Product. is there way to add Price to this Column...?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Widget\Chooser" type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Widget\Chooser"/>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Widget/Chooser.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Widget;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;

class Chooser extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Widget\Chooser
{
    /**
     * Set collection object
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection
     * @return void
     */
    public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
        parent::setCollection($collection);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare columns for products grid
     *
     * @return Extended
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        if ($this->getUseMassaction()) {
            $this->addColumn(
                'in_products',
                [
                    'header_css_class' => 'a-center',
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'name' => 'in_products',
                    'inline_css' => 'checkbox entities',
                    'field_name' => 'in_products',
                    'values' => $this->getSelectedProducts(),
                    'align' => 'center',
                    'index' => 'entity_id',
                    'use_index' => true
                ]
            );
        }

        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'sortable' => true,
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'chooser_sku',
            [
                'header' => __('SKU'),
                'name' => 'chooser_sku',
                'index' => 'sku',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-sku',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-sku'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'chooser_name',
            [
                'header' => __('Product'),
                'name' => 'chooser_name',
                'index' => 'name',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-product',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-product'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'chooser_price',
            [
                'header' => __('Price'),
                'name' => 'chooser_price',
                'index' => 'price',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-product',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-product'
            ]
        );

        $this->sortColumnsByOrder();

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any ideas on how to get this working in Magento 2.3.3?

I've added price as per the above but it's an empty column until you search for a value and then it shows multiple decimal places.

Ideally, I'd like to add Attribute Set as a filter or a different custom product attribute but can't figure it out.